# Garbage value given as output

Tags: c, struct

```
struct book{
    char novel[20];
    char author[20];
    int pages;
    float price;
};

void details(struct book b1){
    printf("\nEnter the name of novel,author,no. of pages and price:");
    scanf("%s",b1.novel);
    scanf("%s",b1.author);
    scanf("%d",&b1.pages);
    scanf("%f",&b1.price);
    }
int main(){
    struct book b1;
    details(b1);
    printf("***NOVEL Details***\n");
    printf("\n%s",b1.novel);
    printf("\n%s",b1.author);
    printf("\n%d",b1.pages);
    printf("\n%.2f",b1.price);

return 0;
}
```

I've tried the same program with a structure of arrays and it works completely fine. Problem arises when a single structure is passed into function and it gives garbage value. I guess there is some problem when calling by value and not address. Please correct me if you find any error

Comment: Any decent book, class or tutorial should have mentioned that arguments to functions are passed *by value*. This means the value is *copied* into the argument variable in the function, and the function only operates on this *copy*. Modifying a copy of course doesn't modify the original. Solve it by either *emulating pass by reference* (by passing a *pointer* to the `b1` structure, i.e. `&b1`) or by simply returning the structure instead of passing as an argument.

Comment: You need to learn how function parameters work. In `details(b1)` you give a _copy_ of your `b1` structure. So you need to give the function `details` a pointer to your `b1` variable

Comment: You need to pass the address of the structure, so the called function can modify it.  Passing a copy of the structure is useless since the copy is discarded when the function returns.

Comment: @JAYL and adii_turbo both of you should read what is the difference between passing by value, pointer and reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the problem is happening due to not passing by reference. Otherwise b1 in main isn't being set and you are just printing whatever values it was initialized with.
Try passing your struct as by reference instead of value for details function
from

```
void details(struct book b1)
```

to

```
void details(struct book * b1)
```

and changing b1.novel to b1->novel where it is appropriate (in the details() function). You use this syntax for struct pointers. b1->novel is just syntactic sugar for (*b1).novel which is dereferencing the pointer before access the value